# Asp.net gridview cells without value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, cells

Now I'm trying to use a gridview control to display three columns "high risk","further investigate" and "low risk"; and sum three columns at the footer. Actually every cell data has been retrieved from database successfully(the sum number of three columns are correct) but the weird thing that is all cells is empty, without any number to show(I use (null) to present the empty cells). You can see the gridview result as below shows:

------------------------------------------------
             high risk     |further risk|         low risk       
---------------|------------|---------------------
              (null)                    (null)                      (null)           
---------------|------------|---------------------
              (null)                        (null)                            (null)         
---------------|------------|---------------------
               (null)                  (null)                      (null)          
---------------|------------|---------------------
SUM       20         |               50           |  30

aspx.code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" style="margin-left: 354px" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="269px" Width="440px" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField>  </asp:BoundField>

            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="High Risk" SortExpression="numberOfhigh">

            <ItemStyle BackColor="Red" />

            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Further Risk" SortExpression="numberOffurther">

            <ItemStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />

            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Low Risk" SortExpression="numberOflow">

            <ItemStyle BackColor="#33CC33" />

            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

code-behind:

```
if (DropDownList2.SelectedIndex == 1 && DropDownList1.SelectedIndex ==1 )
                {
                    GridView1.Visible = true;
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    //string cmdText = "SELECT [numberOfhigh],[numberOffurther],[numberOflow] FROM [rampDB].[dbo].[Assessment] WHERE [AssessmentID] ='" + Session["assid"] + "'";
                    string cmdText = "SELECT [numberOfhigh],[numberOffurther],[numberOflow] FROM [rampDB].[dbo].[Assessment]";
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, sqlConn);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                }
```

And gridview rowdatabind event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //sum result at the footer
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            sum1 += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "numberOfhigh"));
            sum2 += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "numberOffurther"));
            sum3 += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "numberOflow"));
        }
        // Display totals in the gridview footer
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Sum risk";
            e.Row.Cells[0].Font.Bold = true;
            e.Row.Cells[1].Font.Bold = true;
            e.Row.Cells[2].Font.Bold = true;
            e.Row.Cells[3].Font.Bold = true;

            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = sum1.ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = sum2.ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = sum3.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BoundField element of a GridView requires a property "DataField" to know what data to display.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DataTableFieldName" HeaderText="Any Text" />
```

Comment: Thanks, solved it! I forgot it when I create the table.